# Doctrine saving only one result to the DB

Tags: php, symfony, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i have this code,

```
foreach ($res_arr as $key => $value) {
    $post = array(
        'details_id'=>$key,
        'classsubject_id'=>$cs_id,
        'term'=>$term,
        'marks_obtained'=>$value,
        'remarks'=>''
    );
    $marks->fromArray($post);
    $marks->save();
     print_r($post);
}
```

but its adding only one result to the database, and when i print the result in the loop it is printing this data

```
 Array
(
    [details_id] => 1
    [classsubject_id] => 10
    [term] => first
    [marks_obtained] => 23
    [remarks] => 
)
Array
(
    [details_id] => 6
    [classsubject_id] => 10
    [term] => first
    [marks_obtained] => 23
    [remarks] => 
)
Array
(
    [details_id] => 7
    [classsubject_id] => 10
    [term] => first
    [marks_obtained] => 23
    [remarks] =>


)
```

it is only adding the last array result to the database
help me out someone

Answer (score 0):

So i have found that you have to create new instance every time you add data to the database using doctrine. so every time in loop you have to create new instance of the model and than save the data...